# How can i insert files into access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I search whole site and articles but i can't find it. How can i insert files into access database (in desktop application). Please someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a column of type `LONGBINARY` in your table and store the file in that column

Article [Reading, Storing, & Writing Binary Large Objects (BLOBs)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103257) explains how you can achieve it

Answer (score 0):

short answer: you can't. long answer: you can read them, transfer them into blobs and store them as binary fields, along with file name and stuff, simulating a file system. But chances are that's not the best solution for your problem. Care to elaborate on your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that tells you how to [attach files and graphics to the records in your database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-HA001213852.aspx) for Access 2007. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't recommend doing this. It would be more efficient to simply store the path of the file and reference that where needed. If you must, here is the C# code to read the file.

Here is a function to read the file:

```
public static byte[] ReadFile(string filePath)
{
  byte[] buffer;
  FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  try
  {
    int length = (int)fileStream.Length;  // get file length
    buffer = new byte[length];            // create buffer
    int count;                            // actual number of bytes read
    int sum = 0;                          // total number of bytes read

    // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)
    while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
      sum += count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
  }
  finally
  {
    fileStream.Close();
  }
  return buffer;
}
```

You would then want to use an OLE Object field in your database to store the file.

Answer (score 0):

In design view of access set the column's type as file or even byte and give some bigger values.
then use the Stream class to read the file and convert everything read from it to byte and store in your database.